# Python built exe process to kill itself after a period of time

Tags: python, process, terminate

How is it possible to get a compiled .exe program written in Python to kill itself after a period of time after it is launched?

If I have some code and I compile it into an .exe, then launch it and it stays in a 'running' or 'waiting' state, how can I get it to terminate after a few mins regardless of what the program is doing?

The reason why is that the exe that is launched envokes a URL using PAMIE and automates some clicks. What I have noticed is that if the browser is closed the process remains in memory and does not clean itself up. I wanted to find a way to auto-clean up the process after say 5 mins which is more then enough time. I've tried using psutils to detect the process but that does not work in my case. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is the fact that it's an exe so important?

Comment: More importantly, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
def one(Time):
    time.sleep(Time)
    sys.exit(0)

def two():
    thread.start_new_thread(one, (600,)) #10min countdown..
    #Your running function here....Will run sim. with function one. when time ends,
    #sys.exit exits program..(Not tested:) )

two()
```

Comment: You should use threading rather than thread. Why did you select thread module? Some words to explain the concept here would also help.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The reason why is that the exe that is launched envokes a URL using PAMIE and automates some clicks. What I have noticed is that if the browser is closed the process remains in memory and does not clean itself up. I wanted to find a way to auto-clean up the process after say 5 mins which is more then enough time. I've tried using psutils to detect the process but that does not work in my case. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the threading is almost similiar approach, just used this because it was fastest

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a thread when your process starts.
2. Make that thread sleep for the required duration.
3. When that sleep is over, kill the process.